# How to read/write to eeprom of xmega64a4u?

Tags: c

I want to write to eeprom of xmega64a4u and read data from it

```
nvm_t.ADDR0 = EEPROM_START; //nvm_issue_command(NVM_CMD.[CCP_t.CCP_IOREG_gc]);
nvm_issue_command(NVM_CMD_ERASE_EEPROM_gc); // erase eeprom
//nvm_issue_command(NVM_CMDEX_bm); // Set the CMDEX bit in the NVM CTRLA register.

nvm_wait_until_ready();
nvm_t.DATA0 = char1;
nvm_issue_command(NVM_CMD_LOAD_EEPROM_BUFFER_gc);       // load buffer
nvm_t.ADDR0 = EEPROM_START;         


nvm_wait_until_ready();
nvm_t.ADDR0 = EEPROM_START;
nvm_issue_command(NVM_CMD_ERASE_WRITE_EEPROM_PAGE_gc);      // erase and write eeprom

nvm_wait_until_ready();
nvm_t.ADDR0 = EEPROM_START;
nvm_issue_command(NVM_CMD_READ_EEPROM_gc);          // read eeprom


lcd_cmd(0x01);
lcd_select_location(0x01,0x00);
lcd_puts(nvm_t.DATA0);
```

is this the correct way to write and read? I have gone through the data sheets thoroughly, they have given the steps and i have written the code accordingly but it is not working.Actually here i have taken only a character which i want to store in the eeprom first, read it and display it on the lcd. The code shows no error, so i program it into the controller, but my lcd display remains empty. i cannot see the hard coded data on the display. I think i am making a mistake while writing the address.
Please help as I am new to coding.Thanks in advance!

Comment: "is this the correct way to write and read?" This comment should be included in your question. "but it is not working" Can you be more specific (edit the question again) did some of your code works? Do you have access to some error messages/codes?

Comment: What is the value of `EEPROM_START`? Do you modify `.ADDR1` and `.ADDR2` fields?

Comment: " #define EEPROM_START     (0x1000) " This is the given value in the datasheet from where the eeprom memory starts. And yes i tried modifying the .ADDR1 and .ADDR2 values as well.              
NVM.ADDR1 = (EEPROM_START >> 8) & 0x1F;
NVM.ADDR2 = 0x00;                                                                             No luck.

Comment: I think you can take a look at [this code](http://microfluidics.utoronto.ca/gitlab/dstat/dstat-firmware/blob/0f2855ab6b3ab52de80702fdef4eb4ca004a845a/DSTAT/src/asf/xmega/drivers/nvm/nvm.c) Which seems doing what you want.

Comment: I am using atmelstudio which has this nvm control driver. I am using functions from this file itself but unfortunately I am doing something wrong which i am not being able to find out. I am sorry, if I am asking the basics.

Comment: what is the contents of variable: `char1`?

Comment: @user3629249 just a character "A"